# Make "About" Window in glade

Tags: python, glade

I tried to create `about` window like `About MATE` in Mate DE on Ubuntu 14.04, and this is the `.py` file that I made :

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import sys
 try:
     import pygtk
     pygtk.require("2.0")
 except:
     pass
 try:
     import gtk
     import gtk.glade
 except:
      sys.exit(1)

 class aboutGTK:
          """About"""

          def __init__(self):

               #Set the Glade file
               self.gladefile = "about.glade"  
                     self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML(self.gladefile) 

               #Create our dictionay and connect it
               dic = { "on_btnabout_clicked" : self.btnabout_clicked,
                   "on_MainWindow_destroy" : gtk.main_quit }
              self.wTree.signal_autoconnect(dic)

          def btnabout_clicked(self, widget):
              print "About"


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     hwg = aboutGTK()
     gtk.main()
```

but when I running the `about.py` that is what I got :

```
$ python about.py 

(about.py:9950): libglade-WARNING **: Expected <glade-interface>.      Got <interface>.

(about.py:9950): libglade-WARNING **: did not finish in  PARSER_FINISH state
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "about.py", line 34, in <module>
  hwg = aboutGTK()
File "about.py", line 22, in __init__
  self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML(self.gladefile) 
RuntimeError: could not create GladeXML object
```

any help please ?

Comment: glade file's content?

Comment: it's a normal about window !

Answer (score 2):

You need to use GTK3 to load a file created with Glade 3.x. As Glade 2.x isn't available in Ubuntu any more switching to GTK3 is your best option.

To use GTK3 in Python you need to switch from PyGTK to to [PyGObject](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/PyGObject?action=show&redirect=PyGObject). See [The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for how to use it.